# Why does hitting Enter on the keypad cause inadvertent switch to different workbook?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, microsoft-excel-2013

Client is using Office 2013 on a desktop running Windows 8.1 Pro. She usually is working with several spreadsheets open and at times when she hits the enter button of her number pad she changes to a totally different workbook and whatever she had just entered into the cell is gone.

She has told me that it does not seem to happen when she uses the other enter key, but she also mostly uses the number pad. I have looked for specific shortcuts that might change a window or something along those lines but have come up short.

It doesn't happen every time and it is hard to lock down a specific chain of events as she is at a remote site and viewing remotely is riddled with lag. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard for a while to see if the behavior continues? Have you run any diagnostics? Or SFC?

Comment: I was thinking about the keyboard but her office is an hour away. What kind of diagnostics would you suggest running?

Comment: Run hardware diagnostics. The manufacturer usually make them available on their sites. Some preload them on their equipment. Depends on the brand and model. Also, check for BIOS updates.

Comment: Diagnostics doesn't give anything she says this is only a problem since she has been upgraded to windows 8 and to office 2013. I am thinking that I might have to go over there and update her PC either after or before hours to windows 10 to see if that could potentially fix the problem

Comment: IMO, upgrading to 10 would not be very high on my list of ways to fix it. There is no guarantee that will resolve anything. It is important to make sure all the Windows 8.1 updates are installed and the BIOS is up to date. I have had customers turn off their updates and miss out on fixes to issues they complain about. I'd take another keyboard, just in case. Good luck with it. :)